# Get some string before the space, and save it in a variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get "John" from the string "John Smith"?

(I don't want to use .substring(); because its on a contact form and the value could vary.)

Basically I need to get everything before the first space. ;)

```
   <h1 id="name">John Smith</h1>

<script>

    var str = document.getElementById("name");

    var first = str.split(" ")[0];

    alert(first);

</script>
```

Comment: var str = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

`"John Smith".split(" ")[0]` will return "John"

In your case, it would be:

```
var str = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
var first = str.split(" ")[0];
alert(first);
```

Comment: Um. I don't see why it wouldn't. I made a JSFiddle to test anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/SGr9P/

Comment: ^ A reference to his previous comment, which suggested that this did not work.

Comment: Hey, Take a look at the code above, what's wrong with it??  Sorry about that previous comment  I was referring to the code above, not yours.  I deleted it.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech ah, I see why. Use `.innerHTML`!

Answer (score 4):

i dont think the above method is 100% correct

one should use

```
str.trimStart().split(" ")[0]
```

it should remove the spaces if present before any characters start.